# jquery resize window click event added many times and ceases to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize

jquery resize window click event added many times and ceases to work

```
   onResize = function() {
        if($(window).width() < 768) {
            $('.menu-item-has-children').on('click', function() {
                $(this).find('.sub-menu').toggle();
            })
        } else {
            $('.menu-item-has-children').off('click');
        }
    }

    var delay = (function() {
        var timer = 0;
        return function(callback, ms){
            clearTimeout(timer);
            timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
        }
    })();

    $(document).ready(onResize);

    $(window).resize(function() {
        delay(function(){
            onResize();
        },1000)
    });
```

here when I change the width or orientation event click stops working
the event listener becomes a lot
http://prntscr.com/hbuazo

Comment: I am trying to understand the issue, it works but after a change in screen width the click event stops working? Are you going smaller than 768?

Comment: yes, you understood it correctly

Answer (score 0):

```
   I went the other way and decided this question like this:


   $(window).resize(function() {

        if( $(window).width() > 768 ){
            $('.menu-item-has-children').removeClass('menu-item-touch');
        }
        if( $(window).width() <= 768 ){
            $('.menu-item-has-children').addClass('menu-item-touch');
        }
    });

    if( $(window).width() > 768 ){
        $('.menu-item-has-children').removeClass('menu-item-touch');
    } else {
        $('.menu-item-has-children').addClass('menu-item-touch');
    }

    $(document).on('click', '.menu-item-touch', function() {
        $(this).find('.sub-menu').toggle();
    });
```